# How to set x,y coordinates of elements in xaml pages

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I've been trying to move an image by setting its margin but that only changes it size. I want to move an image by changing its x coordinate. How can I do that(in xaml, pages and not wpf)?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867017/how-to-move-a-image-using-xaml

Answer (score 0):

You're image may have it's Stretch set to fill the available space. When you change the margin that could give the image more space so the image expands to fit. If you set the StretchMode to None you may see the margin will affect the position instead.