# Double animations with Image in WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, doubleanimation

I want to move car to point 0, 0 with moving animations, but the problem is that I get an error then I use this function - https://gyazo.com/1f47e18f955c12dc1907fcf4d7b19d6a. 
App look:
https://gyazo.com/10fb071534809229cb98955f9fb86231.
There is my code (I found this function in one article [WPF. Easiest way to move Image to (X,Y) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214155/wpf-easiest-way-to-move-image-to-x-y-programmatically)):

```
public void Eiti(Image target, double newX, double newY)
    {
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(target);
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(target);
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(top, newY - top, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(left, newX - left, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim1);
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim2);
    }
```

and xaml:

```
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF695887">
        <Canvas>
            <Image Name="car1" />
        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void Eiti(Image target, double newX, double newY)
    {
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(target);
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(target);
        top = Double.IsNaN(top) ? 0 : top;
        left = Double.IsNaN(left) ? 0 : left;

        var storyboard = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(top, newY, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
        storyboard.Children.Add(anim1);

        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(left, newX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim2, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim2, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
        storyboard.Children.Add(anim2);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: It should start from image initial position according to specified properties Canvas.Top, Canvas.Left in Image.
I've checked and it's working as expected.