# C# How to shift all objects on UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I make it so when a person clicks on a button, all of the objects on the user control shift location 25 to the right?

Comment: What have you tried so far? are all objects `Control`s?

Comment: For a start, I would advise you to put all of these controls in a `Panel`. Then you will only have to move one control (namely, that panel). Grouping them like this seems appropriate, since, if they have to move together, they probably belong together in some way, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to move all controls of the form? Then write something like this:

```
        private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            ctrl.Left += 25;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` and create a recursive method to return all children in the tree for that `UserControl`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild(v=vs.110).aspx

Then you can use a translate transformation and apply it to the control. Using code similar to the answer here [WPF. Easiest way to move Image to (X,Y) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214155/wpf-easiest-way-to-move-image-to-x-y-programmatically)